# Remove the model object from array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, xcode, uicollectionview

Added model objects in an array on selection in collectionView, now need to remove the deselected items from array. But where clause not working as it's a model added in array not any normal data type. Please guide. Below is my code:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    if selectedIndex.contains(indexPath.row) {
        selectedIndex.removeAll(where: { $0 == indexPath.row })
      
        if(userCategories.count > 0){
           
            userCategories.removeAll(where: { $0 == self.categoriesList[indexPath.row] }) // Error in this line
            print(userCategories)
        }
    }else {
        selectedIndex.append(indexPath.row)

        userCategories.append(self.categoriesList[indexPath.row])
        print(userCategories)
    }
}
```

Error is:

```
Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to two 'CategoriesData' operands
```

Model class:

```
class CategoriesData: Codable {
var id: Int?
var name: String?
var status: String?
}
```

Comment: Show your models which stored in userCategories array

Comment: class CategoriesData: Codable {
    var id: Int?
    var name: String?
    var status: String?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To compare 2 custom objects you need to implement `Equatable`

```
class CategoriesData: Codable , Equatable {
    var id: Int?
    var name: String?
    var status: String?
    static func == (lhs: CategoriesData, rhs: CategoriesData) -> Bool {
        lhs.id == rhs.id
    }
}
```

**OR**

```
userCategories.removeAll(where: { $0.id == self.categoriesList[indexPath.row].id })
```

Comment: Please elaborate, didn't understood

Comment: on what base the compiler should decide whether object are equal or not ??? this is the reason of the error message implement  Equatable

Comment: got your point but, the class is already using Codable, how to implement equitable as well

Comment: updating my question as well

Comment: Didn't expected it works like a charm and I wasted more than an hour on it, can't believe